# c# Regex pattern does not find any matches

Tags: c#, regex

I am using this code to find the state in a text file -

```
string pattern = @"Lender:\s(?'name'\w.*)\n\n(?'address'\w.*),\s(?'state'\w\w)";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);
MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(fileContents);
if (matches.Count > 0)
{
    return isStateAbbreviation(matches[0].Groups["state"].Value.Trim()) ? matches[0].Groups["state"].Value.Trim() : null;
}
```

This is my sample string -

```
Lender: Monetary Management of California, Inc. d/b/a Money Mart 

6311 DEBARR RD UNIT #U ANCHORAGE, AK 99504 907-644-0552
```

The problem is that I count is always 0 but when I use an Online regex tester, it finds all the groups identified.  What is wrong with my Regex pattern?

Comment: Which online service you are testing it on? Because to be honest it's the first place where I see `?'address'` syntax, and regexr.com does not know what do you mean by this...

Comment: it's .nets regex engine @DominikSzymański

Comment: my guess is your file contents are not what you are expecting..... possibly in the white space?

Comment: @KeithNicholas All searches on StackOverflow on named groups showed rather `?<name>` syntax, not `?'name'`, so maybe you should try this?

Comment: @DominikSzymański it matches fine in dotnet, given his sample.

Comment: @DominikSzymański  see documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#named_matched_subexpression

Comment: @KeithNicholas Ok, my bad, didn't knew this syntax :) You deserve a cookie ;)

Comment: I figured out the problem .. it does not like the \n\n, I had to change it to (\n|\r|\r\n).

Comment: I suggest you delete this as the question really has no answer in this form

Answer (score 1):

I think it is probable that your file contains `\r\n` and not `\n` at the end of each line since that is the standard for Windows.

Change your pattern to:

```
string pattern = @"Lender:\s(?'name'\w.*)\r\n\r\n(?'address'\w.*),\s(?'state'\w\w)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Following @NetMage's answer, it's better to have:

```
string pattern = @"Lender:\s(?'name'\w.*)\r\n\r\n(?'address'\w.*),\s(?'state'\w\w)";
```